# Updating geofences with low accuracy in background, update position on map at high accuracy, does not work as intended

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm writing an app which use the location for two purposes:

1) It shows the user's location on a map (with navigation-like accuracy) in a location manager instance and delegate, contained in a viewcontroller

2) In the background, even when closed, it gets the nearest 20 points of interest (list stored in userdefaults) and activates a geofence for these, so the user is noticed when getting nearby. This is done by lowest accuracy possible (3km) to save power, and set up in another location manager instance, initiated when the app is first opened.

The problem is, that the CLLocationmanager object seems to be static so when I call it from two different places, it's the same instance that's returned, and the accuracy, intervals etc, seems to be the same, since both delegates are called simultaneously all the time.

Therefore, the geofences setup method is called all the time, when the user just move a little bit, which I want the map to reflect.

Comment: You should modify the settings of a single instance of CLLocationManager, or probably even better, use significant location change mode in the background. And check whether you are currently in the foreground or background when updating the geofences, or check the delta Ove before updating the geofences

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's only one location manager. So reconfigure it when you go into the background and when you come back into the foreground. It may be convenient to switch its delegate to another object at those times as well (so that each delegate object can focus on one problem).

Comment: By switching delegates do you mean...the most recent  object you assign as delegate?

Comment: I mean you can have a LocationDelegate that handles foreground tracking and a completely different one that handles background tracking (it sounds like you have that already). When you go into the background, just call `locationManager.delegate = myBackgroundDelegate` to switch to the other logic. (By "goes into the background" I mean "applicationDidEnterBackground")

Answer (score 0):

> the CLLocationmanager object seems to be static

Yup! `CLLocationmanager object` is a Singleton so different objects cannot be created. To Solve your problem you need check you application status, which can be done using :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground
```

Once you know the application state you can configure CLLocationmanager's object properties accordingly. Hope it helps!